# Twitter Typeahead with jquery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I use typeahead on my website.
At first I use it on an input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control secteur" name="secteur[]">

$('.secteur').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'states',
      displayKey: 'value',
      source: substringMatcher(secteurs)
    }
);
```

Everything works!

Then I would add inputs so dynamtique with. Html () function of jquery:

```
$( "#add" ).click(function() {  
    var code = $( "#donneeExemple").html(); 
    $( "#donneeExemple" ).before( code );
    $('.secteur').typeahead({
          hint: true,
          highlight: true,
          minLength: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'states',
          displayKey: 'value',
          source: substringMatcher(secteurs)
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

But my new fields created does not work!
The fields appear, but the autocomplete does not work ...

Thank you